# Getting type of serialized flatbuffer

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I am looking for a way to tell what kind of object is in serialized form. The reason is, that I want to use object API on some of the objects, and standard flatbuffers on other. Is there any way to do it without creating another base object for both situations?

Comment: You put some data at the start of the serialized data that describes what type of object it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `file_identifier` functionality in the schema, and then calls in the API for testing the presence of that identifier.